# Get New Relic Application Performance Monitoring data using REST API

Tags: ios, newrelic

I would like to consume all the application performance monitoring related data provided by new relic in the form of REST API's so that i can show it in our own dashboard instead of seeing it in New Relic dashboard. Is there REST API's available for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The documentation for the REST API is available [online](https://docs.newrelic.com/docs/apis/rest-api-v2/getting-started/introduction-new-relic-rest-api-v2).

But think twice about obtaining "...all the application performance monitoring related data provided by new relic..." There is a huge amount of data available and you most likely do not need it all. If you attempt to pull out too much you run the risk of encountering [429 errors (Overload Protection)](https://docs.newrelic.com/docs/apis/rest-api-v2/requirements/api-overload-protection-handling-429-errors) and filling your local disk space.

Decide what you want and the longest period you can stand to collect the data at and request just what you need.

Comment: Is it possible to get the crash analysis data using API? I couldn't find detailed crash analysis report in any of the mobile application API

Answer (score -1):

Another option might be to use the EMBED option.  When you edit a chart there is an embed link in the top right of the chart that gives you iframe code.  Maybe not as flexible as what you were looking for, but could be a quick way to get the data out and present it in your own dashboard.

Comment: Given that this isn't an actual answer, it should probably be reserved for the comments section - An actual answer would have been something like YES they do have a rest API, here is the documentation etc, or NO, they don't, here is a work around for etc. Welcome to SO though!

Comment: In addition to crashlos comment, see this https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer